# Adding logic to recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

The below function produces a cartesian product of the input lists.

How can you make it only yield results where the last two numbers are even?

I'm just trying to see an example of how to correctly add logic to a function of this type.

```
def product(ar_list):
    if not ar_list:
        yield ()
    else:
        for a in ar_list[0]:
            for prod in product(ar_list[1:]):
                out= (a,)+prod
                yield out

ar_list=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]              
                
print(list(product(ar_list)))
```

Comment: In this case you need to read the future a little. Test if `ar_list` has two elements or less, and if so, only yield elements where `prod` is even. (i.e. yield if `ar_list` is longer than two elements, or `prod` is even.) This is not possible if `ar_list` is an iterator, as "reading the future" will exhaust it; in this case, you will either need to cheat by duping the iterable before counting the remaining elements, or — simpler — just filter (non-recursively) the results of this generator.

Comment: To be clear: is the expected output: `[(1, 4, 6), (2, 4, 6)]`? If not, please update your post with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to establish an additional recursive case for `len(ar_list) == 2`. As stated previously in the comments, this works only when `ar_list.__len__` is defined.

```py
def product(ar_list):
    if not ar_list:
        yield ()
    elif len(ar_list) == 2:
        ar_list[0] = [x for x in ar_list[0] if x % 2 == 0]
        ar_list[1] = [x for x in ar_list[1] if x % 2 == 0]
        for a in ar_list[0]:
            for prod in product(ar_list[1:]):
                out = (a,) + prod
                yield out            
    else:
        for a in ar_list[0]:
            for prod in product(ar_list[1:]):
                out= (a,) + prod
                yield out
```

---

Really, the simplest way is to filter the results of `itertools.product` and this solution works when `ar_list.__len__` is not defined.

```py
import itertools


def product(ar_list):
    for prod in itertools.product(*ar_list):
        if prod[-2] % 2 == 0 and prod[-1] % 2 == 0:
            yield prod
```

---

A potentially more efficient solution is to filter prior to generating the Cartesian product but does require `ar_list` to be subscriptable.

```py
import itertools


def product(ar_list):
    ar_list[-2] = [x for x in ar_list[-2] if x % 2 == 0]
    ar_list[-1] = [x for x in ar_list[-1] if x % 2 == 0]
    for prod in itertools.product(*ar_list):
        if prod[-2] % 2 == 0 and prod[-1] % 2 == 0:
            yield prod
```

Comment: The recursive solution does not work when the length of the input list is 1. The other two solutions using `itertools.product` do not answer the question since the question specifically asks about adding logic to an existing recursive function.

Comment: @blhsing, I'd argue that "How can you make it only yield results where the last two numbers are even?" implies that `ar_list` has at least two elements. This should be clarified by the asker. You are certainly correct on your last two criticisms.

Comment: If the case where the length of the input list is 1 is not to be dealt with then you (and the OP) should not go even further to deal with the case where the length of the input list is 0 to begin with, as you do with the statement `if not ar_list:`. Having that statement implies that it is the base case of the recursion, and that all subsequent cases onwards should be handled properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a conditional statement that checks if the length of the current input list is still greater than 2, or if not, check if the current item is even, and only yield output for the current item if one of the two conditions is true:

```
def product(ar_list):
    if not ar_list:
        yield ()
    else:
        for a in ar_list[0]:
            if len(ar_list) > 2 or a % 2 == 0: # <== add this line
                for prod in product(ar_list[1:]):
                    out = (a,) + prod
                    yield out
```